# Disable autocomplete search in the Run dialog on Windows

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

I need to disable autocomplete search which is happening when we type a command in the Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey+R</kbd>) on Windows.

For example : If "reg" is typed there, "regedit" shouldn't be suggested as an auto-completion.

I tried to edit the below registry key methods :

> 1. "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete" key name - 
>      "Append Completion" with string value "no".
> 2. Deleting "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU"
>      hive

Both the methods didnt help in disabling autocomplete in the Run dialog. How can we tackle this problem?

Comment: did you restart the machine once you did this registry changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-auto-suggestions-run-file-explorer-windows-10/) you need to create a key "AutoComplete" and in that key a string value "AutoSuggest" with the value "no", for instance via `reg.exe`:

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete /v AutoSuggest /t REG_SZ /d no
```

or by importing a .reg file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete]
"AutoSuggest"="no"
```

The change will become active at the next logon or if you restart the Explorer process that renders the desktop.